# reponsive design for mobile not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with locating the problem that causes a gap on the right hand side of the page when the width of the device is below 385px. I've spent hours looking through all my code twice to try and find problems but to no avail.

Even if someone could tell me how to disable horizontal scroll without the use of `overflow: hidden`

Any help would be appreciated - here is a link to the page - http://acendor.com/recode/

I believe i've screwed up my CSS somewhere but i've checked it and havn't found any issues. If anyone needs any more information just ask.

Comment: What gap are you talking about?

Comment: On mobile devices of width less than 385px, if you scroll to the right there is a gap in the foreground for no apparent reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Jack you can try to remove your footer **padding-right** and you will get your desired result

CSS

```
.footer-wrapper {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    padding: 60px 0 80px;
    width: auto;
}
```